# How to connect to remote WildFly using JMC?

Tags: java, wildfly, jmc

I have a Linux server where I'm running WildFly 10. I work on a Windows machine and I want to profile the remote application server. I've checked that port 9990 is enabled for access via http by accessing `http://<ip>:9990/console` and via JMX access from the JConsole client that comes in WildFly. For the latter, I downloaded WildFly to my machine, went to `%WILDFLY_PATH%\bin\jconsole.bat`, accesed through `service:jmx:http-remoting-jmx://<ip>:9990` and used my credentials, it works properly. Now I want to access vía JMC, but I cannot achieve it. I tried the following:

- Copied jboss-client.jar libraries from `%WILDFLY_PATH%\bin\client` to `%JDK_HOME%\lib\missioncontrol\dropins` and start JMC.
- Executed JMC from cmd and added `-cp:a <location of jboss-client.jar>` param, like this:

  ```
  jmc.exe -cp:a "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_72\lib\missioncontrol\dropins\jboss-client.jar"
  ```

  None of these worked.

I tried access with VisualVM and worked using the last approach but replaced `jmc.exe` by `jvisualvm.exe` and I connected to the external VM with no issues. I wonder if there's any way to achieve this using JMC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since jmc doesn't accept the -cp flag, you have to run like this:

jmc.exe -vmargs -Xbootclasspath/a:<location of jboss-client.jar>

Some more clues might be here: https://community.oracle.com/thread/2592885?tstart=0